# El almacenamiento de la configuracion de phpMyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

Me sale esa advertencia cuando entro al phpmyadmin luego de seleccionar una BD y seleccionar la opcion operaciones, tambien verifico que no me sale la opcion de guardar consultas.... luego me manda a un link que sale:

> Configuración de pmadb... no recibio el OK.

Slds.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Le damos click a averiguar por que. Y nos lleva esta pagina

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego seleccionamos, Crear las tablas de almacenamiento de configuracion de phpMyAdmin, se ve que se crea la BD phpmyadmin, pero continua el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y cual es el problema con eso ??? ya investigaste que puede ser???

Comment: No he encontrado informacion.

Comment: deberías de hacer una búsqueda en Google ... no crees que hay encuentres informacion???

Comment: Edita la pregunta para agregar el mensaje de error completo, a veces aparece la descripción completa al final de la página. También especifica qué sistema operativo y servidor estás usando.

Comment: ¿Ya pulsaste "Averigua por qué"? El primer paso será Crear las tablas de almacenamiento de configuración de phpMyAdmin... tienes el enlace para ello en una de las capturas. Y busca en Google.

Answer (score 0):

Cierto es que, según el tutorial que el  usuario anterior ha compartido, cambiando los valores del archivo 'config.inc.php'

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

por los valores valores

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = '';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pma';

se soluciona el problema del error del almacenamiento, suponiendo que efectivamente sí tienes creada la base de datos pma, la cual se suele llamar 'phpmyadmin'.

Pero (siempre hay un pero)... es **importante** tener en cuenta que, al utilizar esta configuración, el usuario "pma" tendrá acceso a todas las bases de datos del servidor MySQL, por lo que es importante tomar las medidas de seguridad necesarias para proteger su servidor.
Quitas un problema para generarte otro.

Answer (score -2):

simplemente esas respuestas anteriores!!!!!!!!!!!

aquí esta una solución, ojala te ayude como a mi me ayudo!

https://youtu.be/v87CqpeXtuc
XAMPP MySQL Error : Configuration of pmadb... Not OK

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033059/pma-database-not-ok-in-phpmyadmin-upgrade

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/356767)

Comment: Por cierto, las preguntas y respuestas se pueden editar. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.